# How to Entirely Remove Ubuntu and any Trace of it?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uninstall

I've been having problems with Ubuntu recently.  Namely, every proprietary driver I installed caused the system to hang hopelessly and indefinitely after suspending or closing the lid on my Inspiron 15 7559.  I have made the decision to remove Ubuntu and use only Windows 10, which until recently I had been dual-booting.

The first problem:

I deleted the ~400GB partition dedicated to Ubuntu and merged it with the C: drive, and I removed the GRUB bootloader.  Windows boots normally but when I press 'F12' on startup, the 'ubuntu' option is still there.  This option boots into Windows, but I still want it removed.

The second problem:

In my attempt to coax my graphics driver to function properly, I added

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=native acpi_osi="
```

to the GRUB.  And even though the system no longer boots through the GRUB menu, the backlight during boot up is extremely dim.

I have tried creating a Windows USB and running

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Afterwards, I am told "The operation completed successfully," but in truth, this does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Possible solution from a LiveCD:  https://askubuntu.com/a/63613/231142

Answer (score 0):

I think, you get the UEFI boot menu option with 'ubuntu' string. You have to go to the UEFI(BIOS) setting and look for 'Boot options' there you can delete the 'ubuntu' option.